# username and password validation using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this simple problem that I don't know what did I do wrong.

so I have this code:

```
    function validateForm() 
    {
        var validation = true;
        validation &= validateUsername();
        validation &= validatePassword();
        return validation? true:false;
    }

    function validateUsername()
    {
        var username = $('#username').val();

        if( username == "" )
        {
            alert("Login failed, Please enter your username");
            return false;
        }

        else if( username != "username" )
        {
            alert("Login failed, Username Incorrect");
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }

    function validatePassword()
    {

        var password = $('#pass').val();

        if(password != "password")
        {
            alert("Login failed, Password is incorrect");
            return false;
        }

        else if(password == "")
        {
            alert("Login failed, Please enter your password");
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

If I enter no password it should alert that you should enter your password but instead that it is alerting password is incorrect. Why is it not going through all the if's I created?

Comment: I hope this code is purely for research because hardcoding passwords or even checking them in your client side code is a really bad idea

Comment: oh its not yet finish, i just did that for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You swap the conditions, and check for an empty string **before** you check for the correct password

```
function validatePassword() {

   var password = $('#pass').val();

   if(password == "") {
       alert("Login failed, Please enter your password");
       return false;
   } else if(password != "password") {
       alert("Login failed, Password is incorrect");
       return false;
   } else {
       return true;
   }
}
```

right now you're checking if it's **not** the correct password first, and as an empty string probably isn't the correct password, that matches before the check for an empty string.

Comment: hmm what do you mean? take the empty string first before checking for the correct password?

Comment: oh i got it sorry sorry seems like im just tired haha thank you thank you :)

Comment: yes, you need to check first if the password entered is empty or not and then proceed further.